# Installed Ubuntu 20.4.1 "alongside Windows 10" - reboots to Windows. How do I boot to grub?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I've installed Ubuntu 20.4.1 alongside Windows 10 using the [guide in this article](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-ubuntu-20-04-alongside-windows-10-dual-boot).
The target system is an older Core2 Duo with conventional BIOS - No UEFI or secure boot.

Everything went according to the guide until step 9. After installing Ubuntu, it requests remove the install media and reboot. Rather than reboot to grub, it reboots to Windows.

What is the recovery process if the system does not boot to grub?

Comment: Trying the boot repair process from this article [link](https://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/)

Comment: Make sure you have a Windows repair flash drive as well as Ubuntu live installer. Windows will keep turning fast startup back on with updates and then grub will not boot Windows. So you have to temporarily restore Windows boot loader, fix Windows & then restore grub. Windows 10 dual boot works better with newer UEFI systems or install to different drive, so you have two MBR, one to boot Windows and one with grub.

Answer (score 0):

Used boot-repair, and it helpfully pointed out that Ubuntu had been installed to a different drive than the Windows boot drive.  The sd* drive notation in the installer makes details like that easy to miss.  I changed the BIOS boot priority to the Ubuntu drive, and now see grub and can boot to Ubuntu. I checked and it still dual boots to Windows, too.

Comment: Get used to the `sdx#` notation for physical volumes. It's definitely more descriptive than arbitrary letter drives used in Windows.